# chromecast - error creating sender side web application details

Tags: google-cast

I'm working on building integration of chrome cast into our web player. I'm having issues with building sender side of the process. Are there any good examples of the sender side of things?

I've visited this page: https://developers.google.com/cast/chrome_sender but it would be nice to see a hello world equivalent

Comment: Could you post the issues you are having? It is also possible that the issue you are having is being had by other people.

Answer (score 1):

I have a basic working example posted https://github.com/colinmutter/chromecast-sandbox based on the information and sample code in Google's developer guide.